# CollectionView cell moved out of the frame

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` cell that moved out of the collection view frame.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    self.configureCell(cell: self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath, tag: collectionView.tag)
    return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
}
```

[Chick link to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIKJ4.png)

Im using the below sample code.
https://github.com/moonlsd/TagFlowExample

Comment: try this `self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)self.configureCell(cell: self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath, tag: collectionView.tag)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried still same issue. self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        self.configureCell(cell: self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath, tag: collectionView.tag)
       return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)